# UI element keeps upscaling itself upon game start

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, inventory

Pretty new to developing so please excuse any obvious errors.

I'm currently trying to build an inventory system for my game but the item slots keep upscaling themselves upon game start.
The prefab starts with a scaling of: x=1, y=1, z=1;
On game start this inflates to: x=53.1, y=53.1, z=53.1;

Here is the scale of the prefab:[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elU1Y.png)
And here is the scale of the prefab upon game start: [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tM8i.png)

Here is the script to update the items:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UIItem : MonoBehaviour
{
public Item item;
private Image spriteImage;

private void Awake()
{
    spriteImage = GetComponent<Image>();
    UpdateItem(null);
}

public void UpdateItem(Item item)
{
    this.item = item;
    if (this.item != null)
    {
        spriteImage.color = Color.white;
        spriteImage.sprite = this.item.icon;
    }
    else
    {
        spriteImage.color = Color.clear;
    }
}
}
```

And here is the script used to update the slots and to add the items to the inventory:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class UIInventory : MonoBehaviour
{
public List<UIItem> uIItems = new List<UIItem>();
public GameObject slotPrefab;
public Transform slotPanel;
public int numberOfSlots = 16;

private void Awake()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSlots; i++)
    {
        GameObject instance = Instantiate(slotPrefab);
        instance.transform.SetParent(slotPanel);
        uIItems.Add(instance.GetComponentInChildren<UIItem>());
    }
}

public void UpdateSlot(int slot, Item item)
{
    uIItems[slot].UpdateItem(item);
}

public void AddNewItem(Item item)
{
    UpdateSlot(uIItems.FindIndex(i => i.item == null), item);
}

public void RemoveItem(Item item)
{
    UpdateSlot(uIItems.FindIndex(i => i.item == item), null);
}
}
```

Here is the inventory script itself:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
public List<Item> characterItems = new List<Item>();
public ItemDatabase itemDatabase;
public UIInventory inventoryUI;

private void Start()
{
    GiveItem(1);
    GiveItem("Clue 5");
    RemoveItem(1);
}
public void GiveItem(int id)
{
    Item itemToAdd = itemDatabase.GetItem(id);
    characterItems.Add(itemToAdd);
    inventoryUI.AddNewItem(itemToAdd);
    Debug.Log("Added item:" + itemToAdd.name);
}
public void GiveItem(string itemName)
{
    Item itemToAdd = itemDatabase.GetItem(itemName);
    characterItems.Add(itemToAdd);
    inventoryUI.AddNewItem(itemToAdd);
    Debug.Log("Added item:" + itemToAdd.name);
}

public Item CheckForItem(int id)
{
    return characterItems.Find(item => item.id == id);
}

public void RemoveItem(int id)
{
    Item item = CheckForItem(id);
    if (item != null)
    {
        characterItems.Remove(item);
        inventoryUI.RemoveItem(item);
        Debug.Log("Item removed:" + item.name);
    }
}
}
```

I've tinkered on this for the past four hours and have nothing that seems to work. I've tried the Aspect Ratio Fitter and it only made it more. I can try to explain further if needed.

If anyone could help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try instance.transform.SetParent(slotPanel, false)